# H2 Referential integrity constraint violation on update

Tags: sql, h2

I use H2 for integration tests and I have this strange behavior I can't explain. Here are steps to recreate :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;
CREATE TABLE A(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, COLUMN1 VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE B(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, A_ID INT, COLUMN1 VARCHAR(255));
ALTER TABLE B ADD FOREIGN KEY (A_ID) REFERENCES A(ID);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(1,'foo');
INSERT INTO B VALUES(1,1,'foo');
CREATE INDEX IDX1 ON A(ID,COLUMN1);
ALTER TABLE A ADD COLUMN COLUMN2 VARCHAR(255);
UPDATE A SET COLUMN1='bar';
```

This last update generates following error : 
Referential integrity constraint violation: "CONSTRAINT_42_1: PUBLIC.B FOREIGN KEY(A_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.A(ID) (1)";
I've tried the sames steps with HSQLDB with success (no referential integrity constraint violation).
The only workaround I found to make it work with H2 is to drop index before adding column and recreate same index again.

Is there some reason why H2 would complain about a violation, which I don't see, as I'm not updating the ID column ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the database engine. The problem is, the wrong index is used (IDX1 in your case), and the database then thinks the row was removed when in fact it was only updated.

This is now fixed in the trunk, in [revision 5462](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/detail?r=5462). It will be fixed in the next version of H2.